# Regex for phone number being 10 digits and allowing "-" (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

so I got an assesment due and one the regular expressions is a phone digit that has 10 numbers but it also allows dashes "-". However it can only contain 2 dashes and start with 0. eg. 0x-xxxx-xxxx where x can be any digit between 0-9.

So, so far I've come up with the following regexes:

```
^[0-0][0-9-]{1,11}$
^[0-0][0-9-]{11}$
```

In the first one it works but allows any length, if I put 5 numbers it goes through as long as the first one is 0. In the second one I can put 2 dashes followed by each other or just fill it with dashes and it goes through.

Thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match every of the three parts, separated by the dashes, like this:

```
^0\d-\d{4}-\d{4}$
```

This matches 0x-xxxx-xxxx. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nW7wL5/1

If you also want to match the number without the dashes, use

```
^0\d-?\d{4}-?\d{4}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gY0mC3/1

`\d` is the same as `[0-9]` but it's shorter.

Comment: Thanks man that works good, in my case tho I have to use the first one cuz my teacher specified only 0x-xxxx-xxxx needs to be accepted. Thanks for you help and for sharing your knowledge! Cheers!